# Is there a way to collect all methods and their paths from NestJS application?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I need to write middleware to process requests, but some of paths should be excluded. I don't want manually hardcode all of them, so I have an idea:

Create special decorator, which will tag methods to exclude, something like this:

```js
import { ReflectMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
export const Exclude = () =>
  ReflectMetadata('exclude', 'true');
```

Is there a way after creating NestJS application somehow recursively get all methods, annotated with this decorator, to automatically add their paths to exclude in my middleware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've published a reusable module for discovering metadata on your handlers or Injectable classes specifically to support this pattern. You can grab `@nestjs-plus/common` from NPM and then use the `DiscoveryService` to automatically retrieve all matching handlers or classes based on a MetaData token that you provide. Source code is [available on Github](https://github.com/WonderPanda/nestjs-plus/tree/master/packages/common). I'll be continuing to update the docs in the short term but there are several example usages of it included in the repository already.

Under the hood it uses the MetaDataScanner but wraps things up in a nice easy to use API. Looking at the snippet you've posted this could help cut down a significant amount of boilerplate for your particular use case. You can see more advanced usages in the `@nestjs-plus/rabbitmq` module (from the same repository) of how you can use this to [glue together advanced functionality](https://github.com/WonderPanda/nestjs-plus/blob/master/packages/rabbitmq/src/rabbitmq.module.ts).

EDIT:
I've updated the library to support scenarios for discovering controllers and controller methods to support your scenario. [There's a complete test suite that mimics your setup with the `@Roles` decorator you can check out.](https://github.com/WonderPanda/nestjs-plus/blob/master/packages/common/src/discovery/tests/advanced-controller-discovery.spec.ts). After including the `DiscoveryModule` in your imports, and injecting the `DiscoverService` you can find all controller methods using the simplified `methodsAndControllerMethodsWithMeta` API.

```
// Inject the service
constructor(private readonly discover: DiscoveryService) { }

// Discover all controller methods decorated with guest roles or 
// belonging to controllers with guest roles

const allMethods = this.discover.methodsAndControllerMethodsWithMeta<string[]>(
  rolesMetaKey,
  x => x.includes('guest')
);
```

After you've discovered all the methods you're after you can do whatever you want with them, in your case building up a collection of their `RequestMethod` and `path`.

```
const fullPaths = allGuestMethods.map(x => {
  const controllerPath = Reflect.getMetadata(
    PATH_METADATA,
    x.component.metatype
  );

  const methodPath = Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, x.handler);
  const methodHttpVerb = Reflect.getMetadata(
    METHOD_METADATA,
    x.handler
  );

  return {
    verb: methodHttpVerb,
    path: `${controllerPath}/${methodPath}`
  }
});
```

Which would give you back something like this (taken from the linked test suite).

```
expect(fullPaths).toContainEqual({verb: RequestMethod.GET, path: 'guest/route-path-one'});
expect(fullPaths).toContainEqual({verb: RequestMethod.GET, path: 'super/route-path-two'});
expect(fullPaths).toContainEqual({verb: RequestMethod.POST, path: 'admin/route-path-three'});
```

Feel free to provide feedback on the approach/API.

Comment: I have two questions:
1. In my real case I use decorator @Roles, which attaches array of roles (strings) to method or class. And I want to find all methods, containing role 'guest', and all methods from classes, containing role 'guest'. Can you show an example, how to use your library for that?
2. How can I get **full** URL paths for handler, after I get it with `discoveryService.discoverHandlersWithMeta`? Because I need full path inside middleware, to match against `req.url`

Comment: I'll take a crack at updating the answer/providing a working example repo for your use case later today. Busy day at work. The short answer is that the data you get back from `discoverHandlersWithMeta` includes whatever meta information was attached

Comment: @yumaa I'm making some tweaks to the library to help you out. Controllers are treated differently from other Providers in Nest apps so a few things need to be added before this will work for your scenario. I'll update you with a better example once the new version of the package is published

Comment: @yumaa I've updated the answer to show you how what you're looking to do could be accomplished using the DiscoveryService. Let me know if you have any feedback

Comment: That doesn't look like a lot less code, than mine, but definitely much cleaner :) I'll accept it for now and will try to test tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah because your actual scenario is a bit more advanced there's still a bit of boilerplate to pull out all the stuff you need. But the focus was on having a clean API for interacting with the underlying container that didn't require casting to `any` to access protected members etc. Most of the boilerplate comes from the fact that your decorator can be used both on controllers and individual methods so I might see if that pattern can be further hidden behind the Discovery API. If you do try it feel free to give feedback and I'll continue to make improvements

Comment: This is somewhat common in NestJS, I guess, for example you can add Guard, Interceptor, Pipe or Filter on controller or individual method.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking that I might add another discovery option that finds all handlers based on the decorator being applied at the per method level or on the parent controller/injectable. That way getting to the `allGuestMethods` point in the code sample above would just be a one liner

Comment: @yumaa After looking at it I think that this use case comes up often enough that it deserves it's own utility method. Internally it just composes a bunch of other discovery together (like in the previous edit) but this way there's a simple public API to consume. I've released the new version on NPM and updated the sample code here. Lemme know what you think

Comment: Cool, thank you :) I tried, and in my case it works like charm. I see you get controller from method like `x.component`, is it possible to get module further? In NestJS they have MODULE_PATH also, on module level (https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1520), and it is used in `nest-router` package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188894/discussion-between-yumaa-and-jesse-carter).

Answer (score 1):

So... help yourself.

After digging into NestJS sources I found a way, here is direction for those who interested:

```js
import * as pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
import { INestApplication, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestContainer } from '@nestjs/core/injector/container';
import { MetadataScanner } from '@nestjs/core/metadata-scanner';
import { PATH_METADATA, MODULE_PATH, METHOD_METADATA } from '@nestjs/common/constants';

const trimSlashes = (str: string) => {
  if (str != null && str.length) {
    while (str.length && str[str.length - 1] === '/') {
      str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
    }
  }
  return str || '';
};

const joinPath = (...p: string[]) =>
  '/' + trimSlashes(p.map(trimSlashes).filter(x => x).join('/'));

// ---------------8<----------------

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

// ---------------8<----------------

const excludes = Object.create(null);
const container: NestContainer = (app as any).container; // this is "protected" field, so a bit hacky here
const modules = container.getModules();
const scanner = new MetadataScanner();

modules.forEach(({ routes, metatype }, moduleName) => {
  let modulePath = metatype ? Reflect.getMetadata(MODULE_PATH, metatype) : undefined;
  modulePath = modulePath ? modulePath + globalPrefix : globalPrefix;

  routes.forEach(({ instance, metatype }, controllerName) => {
    const controllerPath = Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, metatype);
    const isExcludeController = Reflect.getMetadata('exclude', metatype) === 'true';
    const instancePrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(instance);

    scanner.scanFromPrototype(instance, instancePrototype, method => {
      const targetCallback = instancePrototype[method];
      const isExcludeMethod = Reflect.getMetadata('exclude', targetCallback) === 'true';

      if (isExcludeController || isExcludeMethod) {
        const requestMethod: RequestMethod = Reflect.getMetadata(METHOD_METADATA, targetCallback);
        const routePath = Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, targetCallback);

        // add request method to map, if doesn't exist already
        if (!excludes[RequestMethod[requestMethod]]) {
          excludes[RequestMethod[requestMethod]] = [];
        }

        // add path to excludes
        excludes[RequestMethod[requestMethod]].push(
          // transform path to regexp to match it later in middleware
          pathToRegexp(joinPath(modulePath, controllerPath, routePath)),
        );
      }
    });
  });
});

// now you can use `excludes` map in middleware
```

Comment: what does the  'path-to-regexp' content sample look like ?

Comment: Wow what an old post you've resurrected. Sorry, I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it maybe?

Comment: 'path-to-regexp' is just a NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp

Comment: Thank you for your response. I’ve moved past it and have found directions from your snippet. Many thanks 